# jQuery plugin function in global scope

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Nowadays I have been learning a lot about jQuery plugin development and about jQuery generally . I have made a simple jQuery plugin where I moved outside the initialize() function from the $.fn.testplugin but now the  initialize() function is in the global scope. My question is how to move outside the initialize() function from the $.fn.testplugin but same time make it local scope.

Plugin:

```
(function($){
    function initialize($obj, color){
        $obj.css("color",color);
    };      

    $.fn.testplugin = function(options){
       var defaults = { 
        color: "red"
       };
       var option = $.extend(defaults, options);

       return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);  
        initialize($this, option.color);
       });      
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: But it is not in global scope.

Answer (score 2):

Your `initialize()` function is not in the global scope; you are explicitly creating a closure where it is defined. You cannot access the `initialize()` function from outside your outermost function in the posted code.

Comment: and if I would delete these lines from the code : (function( $ ){  })(jQuery); than the initialize() function would be in global scope ?

Comment: Assuming you have no other closure wrapping this code that you haven't posted, then `initialize()` will be global

Answer (score 0):

use `var` :

```
var initialize = function() {};
```

it will be in the local scope of your anonymous function.

Comment: This is not necessary. Functions are scoped the same as variables, even when declared directly.